# How to use z-index for <g> element in Svg using React state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, svg

I am learning **Svg** using **React**. I have form input which brings me the order number of  inside . I mean the user will enter a number to my form input and I will sort my  which has  element according to that number. I tried **index** as a style but it does not work. I researched it before. **SVG** does not support **z-index**. In this state what should I do? Do you have any recommendations for me? By the way, I am using **g**  inside **SVG** because I will use it for drag and drop.

I call my component with this code :

```
                     <div ref={takeRef} className="center"> 
                                <svg>
                                    {state.dragFrames.map((d, i) => (
                                        <Frame
                                            key={d.id}
                                            data={d}
                                            onDrag={onDrag}
                                            onDragStop={onDragStop}
                                        />
                                    ))}
                                </svg>
                        </div>
```

My Frame component :

```
import React, { useEffect, useState} from "react";
import { DraggableCore } from "react-draggable";

const Frame = React.memo(function Frame(props: any) {
 const render = () => {
        const { z,width,height } = props.data;
      
        return (
            <DraggableCore  onStart={onStart} onDrag={onDraggingFrame} onStop={onDragStop}>

                <g  className="confine"  style={{zIndex:z}} >

                    <rect
                        cursor="grab"
                        width={width}
                        height={height}
                    >

                    </rect>
                </g>
            </DraggableCore>
        )
    }

    return (
        <>
            {render()}
        </>
    )
}
)
export default Frame;
```

Comment: put all your elements in the order you want them displayed i.e. later elements in the DOM will draw on top of earlier elements.

Comment: I know order can be set index number. I am looking for another solution because I did not change my array. @RobertLongson

Comment: You could hide all your elements and show them via <use> but you still have to sort the <use> elements. Painter's model is all there is in SVG.

Comment: Please take a look at this pen: https://codepen.io/osublake/pen/YXoEQe?editors=1010 He is using `appendChild` in order to append the element at the end of the document